# Alteração de loop principal Wordpress impacta no servidor?

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu usei `pre_get_posts` para alterar o loop do meu site Wordpress. A ideia desse loop é não exibir posts que eu defino uma data de expiração, cujo datas são adicionadas em uma `custom field` (`postexpiry`).

Essas consultas via key (presente no meu código) exigem mais trabalho do servidor? Alguém tem uma sugestão melhor do que essa?

Eu sinto que a homepage do meu site está carregando com mais lentidão, já, por exemplo, a página de categorias não.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $q ) {

    if ( (is_home() || is_category() || is_tag() || is_search()) && $q->is_main_query() && !is_admin() )
    {

    $q->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'news' ) );

    $date_now = strtotime(current_time( 'mysql' ));
    $meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'     => 'postexpiry',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'postexpiry',
        'value'   => '0',
        'compare' => '=',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'     => 'postexpiry',
                'value'   => $date_now,
                'compare' => '>',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            ),

        ),

    );

    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

return $q;

}
});
```

Comment: Tem certeza que o problema é `pre_get_posts`? Se bem me lembro, é altamente recomendável usá-lo... já descartou que seja um problema do Theme ou de algum Plugin?